# Can't find variable is_single in my jQuery plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

I converted a jQuery plugin into a Wordpress one where I reference the method is_single():

```
if (is_single()) {
    // Do something
}
```

BTW, this code is in my js file. Is that the mistake I'm making?

The plugin installs and runs correctly, but, I get an error saying is_single can't be found. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: show us your code but is_single() is a WP php function and not a JS function........ there are ways to use php in a JS file though but depends on what your goal is.

Comment: That's it. That's my problem. I thought it was a JS function. Can you direct me how to do it then?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in WP to write php into JS is using wp_footer

```
function sse246626_js() {
 if(is_single()) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
   echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {';
    echo '$("#mydiv").hide();';
   echo '});';
  echo '</script>';
 }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'sse246626_js');
```

This way gives you access to the WP functions as you need, there are probably better ways of doing it if you have lots of JS (php file as a JS file) but it gets slightly complicated as you need to load the WP functions to be used in the file.